# Pygame not working on mac

Tags: python, macos, pygame

I am attempting to use pygame on my mac, I installed it using easy_install and I keep getting the same error when I attempt to compile it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "App.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame-1.9.1release-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/pygame/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame-1.9.1release-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/pygame/base.so, 2): Symbol not found: _SDL_EnableUNICODE
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame-1.9.1release-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/pygame/base.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame-1.9.1release-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/pygame/base.so
```

I can not for the life of me figure out what the problem is. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the osx binary.  Reference is [here](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issue/47/pygamebase-raises-importerror).